# Is a product that contains a non-measurable factor measurable in the product $\sigma-$algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have the following question:

Let $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Suppose $A\subset [0,1]$ is not Borel-measurable. Is the set $A\times [0,1]\times [0,1]\times\dots$ measurable in the product sigma algebra $\bigotimes_{i\in \mathrm{N}}\mathcal{B}([0,1]) $ on $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$?

I could not figure out the answer (although the answer seems to be "Yes", intuitively) - using the measurability of the coordinate projections does not work, since it "goes in the wrong direction" (at least I think so).

Many thanks for any help, I much appreciate it!

Comment: Why can't you use the coordinate projections to come up with a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not measurable. [Sections](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/sections-of-sets-and-functions/) of a measurable set in the product $\sigma$-algebra are measurable, but $A$ is such a section of $A\times[0,1]\times\ldots$. For example, it is the $(x,x,x,\ldots)$-section for any $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: thanks Michael! I thought about sections, but I wasn't sure whether the result also holds for countable products (not just finite ones).